# keystore : 2 passwords requested while I entered only one

Tags: java, keystore, android-keystore

In Visual Studio, I need to sign an Android application.

I already have a keystore that was created using this command line:

`keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore [Path to keystore to create]`

This command asked me to "Enter Keystore Password", which I did, then to "Re-Enter new password". I re-type same password). So at the end I have entered only one password

So now I try to publish my Android App. Visual studio asks me (dialogue "Distribute - Signing Indentity) to import my keystore. In the form I have to enter "keystore Path", "Password", "Alias", "Keystore Password". What password should I enter? It asks 2 passwords, but I have filled only one when I created my keystore (see upper)

What am I supposed to enter for "Password" and "Keystore password"?

[Edit] Here is a screenshot of application "portecle" showing some information about my certificate:
[image]

Comment: Did you use `keytool` from Java 9 or higher? That by default creates a PKCS12-format keystore, while 8 and lower defaults to JKS; a **JKS keystore can have a password for the/an key entry different from the password for the whole store**, but PKCS12 (as implemented in Java) forces the key password the same as the store password without prompting. VSCode is probably allowing for the former case; if so, enter the same password for both the store and the key. (Alternatively, create with `-storetype jks` and you will be able to enter two different passwords, each one repeated for verification.)

Comment: I used jdk-11.0.12, so it would make sense. But in Visual studio I tried to enter twice my password, and "upload" in alias, but it does not work. I added in my question a screenshot of the certificate as seen by UI tool "portecle". It does not make mention of PKS12.

Comment: Is (your) portecle using Java 8? That doesn't reliably distinguish the keystore format. Given you have keytool from 11, do `keytool -list -keystore file` and see what _that_ says for type. I don't use or know about VSCode, but if it dislikes PKCS12 you could try my alternative of creating JKS.

Comment: You were right, sorry I trusted too much a tool. Here is what keytool from jdk11 answers:
"Keystore type: PKCS12, 
Keystore provider: SUN, 
Your keystore contains 1 entry, 
upload, 20 janv. 2022, PrivateKeyEntry,xk". I also created a new key using same command as in my initial post, but adding "keytool -list -keystore file". Visual studio can sign my app with this keystore. So as you suspected, VS is not able to sign an app with PKCS12 keystore. Now, I would like to keep my certificate; Is it possible to convert safely my keystore from PKCS12 to jks, and is it wise to do it?

Comment: To convert ['import' from the PKCS12 to a (new) JKS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html#GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549__IMPORTCONTENTSFROMANOTHERKEYSTORE-507D4101). Is it safe/wise? PKCS12 is more standard (interoperable) and better encrypted, that's why Java (finally) started switching to it as default in 2017; JKS was a hack by Sun to evade US legal restrictions in the 1990s, and really shouldn't have lasted this long but it did. But if only JKS works in VS and you want VS, then you need JKS unless you get the VS people to add PKCS12.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I got an answer from Visual studio team, so it is confirmed as a bug : VS is not compatible with PKS12 certificates. They say they will fix it. Thank you for your explanations and help.